# conversion of string arraylist to double arraylist using lambdas

Tags: java, string, arraylist, lambda, double

I need some help regarding converting string array list to double array list using java lambdas upto  now I had tried these.

```
List<Double> Doublevalues1 = valueItemsToList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this in general

```
 for(int j = 0; j< valueItemsToList.size();j++)
    {
         Doublevalues1.add(Double.parseDouble(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
         //Doublevalues.add(Double.valueOf(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
    }
```

can anyone tell me where I gone wrong This is not duplicate answer I tried all possibilites I had gone through the net but none of them gave me correct answer glad if you could help. 
this is my complete code

```
 public class Stock {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String buff[] = new String[4988];
    int i = 0;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\data.csv");
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String s;
        while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
           // System.out.println(s);
            buff[i] = s;
            i++;
          // String[] s1 = s.split(",");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("error happend at block try at fileinput");
    }
     //converting array string to arraylist
     List<String> valueItemsToList = Arrays.asList(buff);
     //valueItemsToList.forEach(System.out::println);
     List<Double> Doublevalues1 = new ArrayList<Double>();// valueItemsToList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(int j = 0; j< valueItemsToList.size();j++)
    {
         Doublevalues1.add(Double.parseDouble(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
         //Doublevalues.add(Double.valueOf(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
    }
     Doublevalues1.forEach(System.out::println);
}
}
```

error:
its little bit clumsy its here complete

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>       at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
>       at stock.Stock.main(Stock.java:53)
>   C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: "can anyone tell me where I gone wrong" - well you haven't told is what happened, which makes it hard to help you. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: it has  went well when i used integer instead of double only problem is its not going on well with double and file contains only one column data.

Comment: `buff` contains nulls, unless the number of lines just fits. Don't use array, just use `ArrayList<String>` to store `s`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @bayou.io, either use `ArrayList<String>` in place of `buff[]`

*(because if the number of lines in your input file are less 4988 then you will get NullPointerExcetion and if you have more lines then you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)*

or place `null` check before String to Double conversion e.g.

```
for(int j = 0; j< valueItemsToList.size();j++)
{
    if(valueItemsToList.get(j) != null){ // NULL Check
        Doublevalues1.add(Double.parseDouble(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
        //Doublevalues.add(Double.valueOf(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> valueItemsToList = Arrays.asList(buff);
     //valueItemsToList.forEach(System.out::println);
     List<Double> Doublevalues1 = new ArrayList<Double>();// valueItemsToList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(int j = 0; j< valueItemsToList.size();j++)
    {
         Doublevalues1.add(Double.parseDouble(valueItemsToList.get(j)));
         //Doublevalues.add(Double.valueOf(valueItemsToList.get(j)));

    }
     Doublevalues1.forEach(System.out::println);
```

solved thanks for your posts